# Scrapy crawl shows output in terminal but not in json excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am able to show the result of scrape in the terminal, but when i insert -o .csv, the 3rd line of coding will have output in json excel file but not the first and second line ( trying to scrape the start date and end date as shown in picture below)

Coding:

```
 def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css("div.views-row"):
        yield {
            'Max ERC':quote.xpath('.//div[strong[.="Max ERC Funding"]]/following-sibling::text()[1]').extract(),
            'Max ERC1':quote.xpath('.//div[strong[.="Max ERC Funding"]]/following-sibling::text()').extract(),                
            'TEST':quote.xpath('./div[contains(@class, "views-field-acronym")]/span[contains(@class,"field-content")]/text()').extract()
              }
```

Empty in the excel json file

[image]

There are output for Max ERC and MAX ERC1 in terminal:

[image]

The html code:

[image]

Comment: Why your yielded dictionary sequesce not matching your output dictionary sequence in terminal? isnt it should be in a sequece of  `'Max ERC', 'Max ERC1'` and then `TEST` ?

Comment: If you could see output in terminal then `scrapy crawl <spider name> -o file_name.csv` should definately work . Did u happen to miss specifying file_name ?

Comment: yup the output should follow the yield sequence so i think something has gone wrong, and definitely i have inserted the file_name because there is an excel file as stated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I guess it's the *list* messing with the *csv*, generally I want to avoid that. Can you try if this parser fix the issue?

```py
fund, _, start_end_date = r.xpath('.//div[strong[.="Max ERC Funding"]]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
fund = fund.strip()
# import re
start_date, end_date = re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", start_end_date)
acronym = r.xpath('./div[contains(@class, "views-field-acronym")]/span[contains(@class,"field-content")]/text()').extract()[0]
yield {
  "fund": fund,
  "start_date": start_date,
  "end_date": end_date,
  "acronym": acronym
}
```